# How to implement REST API with grpc bidirec streaming?

Tags: rest, go, grpc-go

Is it possible to expose a REST API service using grpc bidirectional streaming?
Example: A rest API call that a user makes should trigger a directional streaming call and send the response back to the user via HTTP streaming. I am able to do this from the client side (that is have the http handler signature logic on client), but unable to do the same from the server side.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you taken a look at how [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/runtime/handler.go#L50) does this? (it's not really clear from your question if you are intending to use `grpc-gateway` or roll your own handler).

Comment: Hi, i haven't taken a look at the grpc gateway yet but was trying to implement my own HTTP handler using gorilla mux. Is the above possible only with grpc gateway?

Comment: You can implement this yourself if you want. [gRPC gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) is written in Go and [supports streams](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#supported) (but not "True bi-directional streaming") so  [its sourcecode](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/runtime/handler.go#L50) may help you get started implementing your own 'gateway' (your code should be a bit simpler).